# react, gatsby - how to access GraphQL query data in react class component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, graphql, gatsby

I've a `react` component named 'Header' in `/src/components` directory in `gatsby` defined as below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import "./header.css"

class Header extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return(
                <Img fixed={data.file.childImageSharp.fixed} />
            )
        }
    }

    export default Header

    export const query = graphql`
      query {
        file(relativePath: { eq: "logo.png" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            # Specify the image processing specifications right in the query.
            # Makes it trivial to update as your page's design changes.
            fixed(width: 125, height: 125) {
              base64
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
```

I tried to use `StaticQuery` with function component but it didn't work. So, I want to stick to the class component syntax.

Here, the query executes fine in `http://localhost:8001/___graphql`

**How do I access query data in `react` class component ?**

Comment: @BenBachem yes and got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined` error

Comment: Throw a `console.log(this)` into your render function. I think you'll find the data prop has this info nested in it. Probably `this.props.data.file` I think.

Comment: Hey @Valay, you have to use StaticQuery with components. Global query (like you're using in this example) will be ignored by gatsby in non-page component. What is the problem that you have with StaticQuery?

Comment: also, if it were in a page component, you'd need to get it from props, so `this.props.data.file...` like @staypuftman pointed out

Comment: @Derek Nguyen yes you are right. I used `StaticQuery` and {...props} and it's working fine now. But got another issue- as I have functional component how do I add window scroll event listener. Previously I was using class component and window scroll was working fine in componentDidMount.

Comment: @Valay I'm sure you can use class component syntax with StaticQuery as well -- you can use componentDidMount that way

Comment: Hi, try with that <Img fixed={props.data.file.childImageSharp.fixed} />

Answer (score 1):

Only page component files can export a `query` variable to query like your example shows. See *[Use a page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-four/#use-a-page-query)* in the Gatsby documentation.

Here's an example of `StaticQuery` usage with a class component. You have to wrap the class component with a functional component to make it work.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'

class CoolThing extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.site.siteMetadata.title}

        {/* conditionally render directories */}
        {this.props.directories.edges && (
          <ul>
            {this.props.directories.edges.map((directory) => {
              return <li key={directory.node.id}>{ directory.node.name }</li>
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
        allDirectory {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={(data) => (
      <CoolThing site={data.site} directories={data.allDirectory} />
    )}
  />
)
```

[Here is a related discussion](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10523) on the topic.

You may also consider using [Gatsby's `useStaticQuery` hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/).